# Mouseover skips some elements, when i'am “flash”

Tags: javascript

sometimes if i'm "Flash" and i move speedy mouse, mouseover event skips some elements.

I try to implement a selectable "event", and everything works fine only if i "drag" in a normal way, have anyone a solution for that ?

PS : mouseenter not work for my feature, and i can't use jQuery, everything must be pure js

```
    element
        .on('mousedown', function() {
            mouseButton = true;
        })
        .on('mouseover', function() {
            if (mouseButton) {
                //push in array
            }
        })
        .on('mouseup', function() {
            mouseButton = false;
        })
```

Comment: How about show your code, let us know what your have tried?

Comment: element
            .on('mousedown', function() {
                mouseButton = true;
            })
            .on('mouseover', function() {
                if (mouseButton) {
                    //push in array
                }
            })
            .on('mouseup', function() {
                mouseButton = false;
            })

Answer (score 0):

Mouseover events do not always fire if the pointer is moved very rapidly across the display.